# parametric GADT from the outside

Tags: ocaml, gadt, locally-abstract-type

GADT allows some form of dynamic typing:

```
type _ gadt =
  | Int: int -> int gadt
  | Float: float -> float gadt

let f: type a. a gadt -> a = function
  | Int x -> x + 1
  | Float x -> x +. 1.
```

I'd like to be able to do the same kind of dispatch, but with a parametrized type, with the parameter of the gadt accessible from the outside.
If the parameter is universally quantified, or fixed, this is easy:

```
type (_,_) container = 
  | List: 'a list -> ('a,'a list) container

let f : type a b. (a,b) container -> b = fun (List l) -> l
let g : type a b. a -> (a, b) container -> b = fun x (List l) -> x::l
let h : type b. (int, b) container -> b = fun (List l) ->  1::l
```

However if there are other form of constraints on the parameter this does not work:

```
class ['a] ko (x:'a) = object 
    method m : type b. ('a, b) container -> b = fun (List l) -> x::l
end
```

I get the error: *The type constructor a#0 would escape its scope*.
I guess this is due to outside-in restriction, without fully understanding the domain.

The only solution I found was to use Higher module:

```
open Higher
module Higher_List = Newtype1 (struct type 'a t = 'a list end)
type ('a,_) container = List: 'a list -> ('a, Higher_List.t) container

class ['a] c (x:'a) = object
    method m : type b. b container -> ('a,b) app = fun (List l) -> Higher_List.inj(x::l)
end
```

This solution is far from being perfect however: first it is verbose, with inj and prj everywhere, and more importantly, it have a lot of limitation: the 'a parameter can't have constraints, nor variance...

Is anyone aware of a better solution ?

**Edit**

After some thinking, Drup solution is working, but it must be taken with care ! In my full problem (not the toy program in this question) I need to have access to self in the method definition. So going back to Drup solution, I must pass self to the intermediate function, and to do so, I must give it a type. So I must first declare a class type...

```
class type ['a] c_type = object
    method m: ('a, 'b) container -> 'b
end

let cons : type a b. a c_type -> a -> (a,b) container  -> b =
    fun self x (List l) -> x::l

class ['a] c (x:'a) = object(self: 'a #c_type)
    method m = cons (self :> 'a c_type) x
end
```

This won't work however if class `c` have a constraint on `'a`: the type of `cons` won't be valid, as `a`must be universally quantified but have a contraint in `a c_type`. The solution is to write `c_type` without the constraint on `'a`. Note however that this means a lot of rewriting. In many cases, just omitting the constraint is not sufficient to make it disappear: all of its usage must be unconstraint...

So the final solution looks like:

```
type (_,_) container = 
  | List: 'a list -> ('a,'a list) container

class type ['a] c_type = object
    (* no constraint on 'a, and take care of its usage ! *)
    method m: ('a, 'b) container -> 'b
end

let cons : type a b. a c_type -> a -> (a,b) container  -> b =
    fun self x (List l) -> x::l (* in real code, self is used... *)

class ['a] c (x:'a) = object(self: 'a #c_type)
    constraint 'a = < .. > (* well just for the example *)
    method m = cons (self :> 'a c_type) x
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why try complicated when you can do simple ? :)

```
type (_,_) container =
  | List: 'a list -> ('a,'a list) container

let cons : type a b. a -> (a, b) container -> b = fun x (List l) -> x::l

class ['a] ko (x:'a) = object
    method m : type b. ('a, b) container -> b = cons x
end
```

This kind of constructions are tricky, since the placement of the locally abstract type is important. In your case, you would like a locally abstract type at the outer layer of the class (for the type `a`) which is not possible. Making an intermediate, properly abstracted, function usually helps.

Also, do not use `higher`. It's a proof that you can encode HKT in the module system, not an encouragement to actually do it.

Comment: where is this Higher module coming from.

Comment: As an author of `higher` I disagree that it is merely a proof of concept. It is designed to be used -- just not very often. There are use cases where using `higher` results in cleaner code than using functors -- see [the paper](http://www.lpw25.net/flops2014.pdf) for some examples.